# http://localhost:3000/songs/10 id error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When submitting (creating) a song on my app I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/songs/10` for example but see "The page isn't redirecting properly". For some reason the `song_id` is 10 when it should be 1 as I've deleted all songs from the database.

If you look at the [songs_controller.rb](https://github.com/Apane/leap/blob/master/app/controllers/songs_controller.rb) as well as [songs#show.html.erb](https://github.com/Apane/leap/blob/master/app/views/songs/show.html.erb) you will see the code that I think may be causing the problem. I've also associated all of the models correctly following the rails.api directions. Not sure why I am getting a 'Problem loading page error' message after creating a song. I've looked into how Ryan Bates does this and my code is identical. Please advise :)

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord hands out successive IDs for records, starting with 1. 
Even is you delete records, the IDs will never go back to a lower number.

So if you add 10 songs, and delete 9, then add another song, that song will get ID 11.

Each database table will remember which was the last ID which was handed out, and the next ID will always be +1 larger than the last ID.